# Unable to call PASSWORD() with VARCHAR() parameter inside a procedure

Tags: mariadb

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE custUpdateInfo(IN customer_id varchar(20), IN passwordd VARCHAR(20), IN named varchar(20), IN addressd VARCHAR(60), IN phone_number DECIMAL(10) UNSIGNED, IN email_id VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
    IF (CHAR_LENGTH(passwordd) > 0) THEN
      UPDATE Users SET Users.passcode = passwordd WHERE Users.username = customer_id;
    END IF;
    IF (CHAR_LENGTH(passwordd) > 0) THEN
      set password for customer_id = PASSWORD('hi');
    END IF;
    IF (CHAR_LENGTH(named) > 0) THEN
      UPDATE customer SET customer.name = named WHERE customer.customer_id = customer_id;
    END IF;
    IF (CHAR_LENGTH(addressd) > 0) THEN
      UPDATE customer SET customer.address = addressd WHERE customer.customer_id = customer_id;
    END IF;
    IF (CHAR_LENGTH(phone_number) > 0) THEN
      UPDATE customer SET customer.phone_number = phone_number WHERE customer.customer_id = customer_id;
    END IF;
    IF (CHAR_LENGTH(email_id) > 0) THEN
      UPDATE customer SET customer.email_id = email_id WHERE customer.customer_id = customer_id;
    END IF;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

This code works, but the following doesn't:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE custUpdateInfo(IN customer_id varchar(20), IN passwordd VARCHAR(20), IN named varchar(20), IN addressd VARCHAR(60), IN phone_number DECIMAL(10) UNSIGNED, IN email_id VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
    IF (CHAR_LENGTH(passwordd) > 0) THEN
      UPDATE Users SET Users.passcode = passwordd WHERE Users.username = customer_id;
    END IF;
    IF (CHAR_LENGTH(passwordd) > 0) THEN
      set password for customer_id = PASSWORD(passwordd);
    END IF;
    IF (CHAR_LENGTH(named) > 0) THEN
      UPDATE customer SET customer.name = named WHERE customer.customer_id = customer_id;
    END IF;
    IF (CHAR_LENGTH(addressd) > 0) THEN
      UPDATE customer SET customer.address = addressd WHERE customer.customer_id = customer_id;
    END IF;
    IF (CHAR_LENGTH(phone_number) > 0) THEN
      UPDATE customer SET customer.phone_number = phone_number WHERE customer.customer_id = customer_id;
    END IF;
    IF (CHAR_LENGTH(email_id) > 0) THEN
      UPDATE customer SET customer.email_id = email_id WHERE customer.customer_id = customer_id;
    END IF;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

The difference is in line

```
set password for customer_id = PASSWORD(passwordd);
```

which was originally

```
set password for customer_id = PASSWORD('hi');
```

The error I get is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'passwordd);
>       END IF;
>       IF (CHAR_LENGTH(named) > 0) THEN
>         UPDATE custom' at line 7

Comment: You should add more details. What's the error message?

Comment: I added more info. Basically `set password for customer_id = PASSWORD('hi');` is working but `set password for customer_id = PASSWORD(passwordd);` isn't.

Comment: You are missing the `UPDATE` on that line, yes? Or is that just a transcription problem?

Comment: It seems that it requires a plaintext password. [Maria db docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/password/)

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought as well. Currently I am working around this by calling `set password...` query from front end instead of using a procedure. Is there a way to do this inside a procedure?

Comment: Code still makes no sense to me without the UPDATE on that line. What are you trying to set? The input variable? I'm confused, but it sounds like you guys are on top of things.

Comment: I just refered MariaDB docs for updating password and you can see there that they don't write `UPDATE` for it. Link: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/set-password/

Comment: My bad! I thought you were updating the Users table with a password column in it.

Comment: You may have to resort to updating the user table directly as the `SET PASSWORD FOR ..` and `ALTER USER ... IDENTIFIED BY ...` syntaxes don't seem to accept a variable for the password or password hash.

Comment: What version of MariaDB?  Is there an "auth" plugin?